# Installing Java 1.6 Update 141 on CentOS

Tags: java, oracle, centos

I am having an issue finding (and therefore installing) **Java 1.6 Update 141** (or greater) on CentOS.

I have a Java application that only runs in **Java 1.6** (I know, updating the app is the "correct" answer, but thats not an option right now), and it will only run correctly with version `1.6.0_141-b32` because I need to **TLSv1.6** enabled. I have found the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_141) for this version, but can't find out how to download and install this specific version.

Can someone point me in the correct direction to install `Java 1.6.0_141-b32`? on CentOS? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Can you get the `rpm`? if so `yum localinstall Java 1.6.0_141-b32.rpm`

Comment: I can't seem to find the rpm. Which seems odd to me. Maybe because its such an old version.

Comment: Java 1.7 and 1.8 should be compatible.  There should be a configuration in the Jar file that says "treat us as 1.6", so it should work.  Have you tried a later version and saw it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a version of Java 6 that is only available to people with an Oracle Java support contract.

If you did ever find it in a public repo, then *someone* is most likely violating an Oracle contract by making it available.  And you would be placing yourself at legal risk by downloading it.   (Copyright violation to start with.)

So if you need Java 1.6 Update 141, get a support contract ... and Oracle will tell you where to get the RPMs from.

It is worth checking the detailed Java version history.  Java 1.6 Update 45 was the last public release of Java 6.  In April 2013.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history